# Adding new terms to a bag-of-words model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I'm using k-means clustering to group a set of news items. I'm using the bag-of-words model to represent the documents, more specifically, each document is represented as the term frequency vector.

My question: how can I add new documents without having to recalculate all the term frequency vectors (seen that the vocabulary containing all the terms for all the docs will change)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy solution is to use the vocabulary from the documents you've already seen, ignoring any new terms; this is customary in document classification.

Another solution, that's become popular in recent years, is to ditch the vocabulary altogether and use [feature hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing).

A third possibility is to reserve space in your feature vectors for future terms. E.g., let's say you're vectorizing a bunch of documents with a vocabulary of size *N*, then you actually turn them into vectors of size *N* + *K* with the final *K* initially set to zero, so you can add up to *K* terms to the vocabulary later on.

(What is probably not a solution is to compute dot products, means, etc. on hash tables directly. It would be the most flexible approach, but it's usually *very* slow.)

Comment: Do you know how this is implemented in scikit's TfidfVectorizer ?

Comment: @pnsilva: what exactly? Ignoring new terms is what `TfidfVectorizer.transform` does; feature hashing is [work in progress](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/909) by yours truly; the third possibility is not directly supported.